# How To dynamically generate an HTML Table using ngFor. in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table, ngfor

I am trying to dynamically generate the following html table, as seen on the screenshot
[image]

I was able to manually create the table using dummy data, but my problem is that I am trying to combine multiple data sources in order to achieve this HTML table structure.

SEE [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkatki?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for the full example.

The Data looks like this (focus on the activities field):

```
    let data = {

id: '60bf06e6fc8f613117de1db9',
    activities: {
      '0': ['Power', 4, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '1': ['Attitude', 2, '', 3, '', 0, ''],
      '2': ['NR', 4.5, '', 1.5, '', 0, ''],
      '3': ['FMS', 4, '', 4, '', 0, ''],
      '4': ['Automation', 2.5, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '5': ['Path', 4.5, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '6': ['Systems', 2, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '7': ['Environment', 4.5, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '8': ['Planning', 2, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '9': ['Co-ordinate', 4.5, '', 3, '', 0, ''],
      '10': ['Prioritize', 2.5, '', 3, '', 0, ''],
      '11': ['Workload', 4.5, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '12': ['Crew', 4, '', 3, '', 0, ''],
      '13': ['ATC', 2.5, '', 3, '', 0, ''],
      '14': ['Identify', 4, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '15': ['Ass. Risk', 2, '', 4.5, '', 0, ''],
      '16': ['Checklist', 4, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],
      '17': ['Analysis', 3, '', 3, '', 0, '']
    }}
```

The activities field has a total of 18 activities. Each one is identified by its id, and an array of activities. For instance `'0': ['Power', 4, '', 2.5, '', 0, ''],`. '0' represents the id of the activity `Power`. 4 represents Attempt1 - Grade & '' represents Attempt1 - Note; etc (Refer to the screenshot for clarification).

The complete list of activities is stored in a different variable/file and has the following structure.

**Component.ts**

```
        this.activities = [{
                "id": 0,
                "activity": "Power",
                "subject": "Control",
                "icon": "icon-link"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "activity": "Attitude",
                "subject": "Control",
                "icon": "icon-link"
            },{...}]
    this.groupedActivities = customGroupByFunction(this.activities, 'subject');
this.colors = {Control: '#bfbfbf', 'AFCS': '#bfbfbf', ...}
    this.activitiesListKey = Object.keys(this.activitiesList);
```

Below is my html code.

```html
        <table>
        <caption>Session Summary</caption>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 40%"></th>
          <th style="width: auto"></th>
          <!-- Loop through AttemptCount variable
            to populate this heading -->
          <th style="width: auto" colspan="2" *ngFor="let attempt of attemptCounts(3)">Attempt {{attempt}}</th>
    
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 40%">Subject Grouping</th>
          <th style="width: auto"></th>
    
          <!-- Populate these heading using the formula
            AttemptCount * 2 (columns - Grade & Note) -->
          <ng-container *ngFor="let attemptLabel of attemptCounts(3)">
    
            <th style="width: auto">Grade</th>
            <th style="width: auto">Note</th>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
    
        <!-- Loop through all Activity Subjects
        And create heading accordingly. 6 Main Subjects so far -->
    
        <!-- Next Subject -->
    
        <ng-container *ngFor="let id of activitiesListKey">
          <tr>
    
            <!-- Generate [Rowspan] = (Subject.Array.Length + 1) -->
            <th style="width: 40%;" rowspan="4" [style.background]="colors[id]">
              {{id}}</th>
    
            <!-- Loop through each Subject.Array Elements
            and populate -->
          <tr style="width: auto">
            <th>Power</th>
            <td>2.6</td>
            <td>Can Improve</td>
            <td>5.0</td>
            <td>Excellent</td>
            <td>4.5</td>
            <td>Regressed</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="width: auto">
            <th>Attitude</th>
            <td>4.0</td>
            <td>Fantastic</td>
            <td>4.5</td>
            <td>Getting Better</td>
            <td>5.0</td>
            <td>Nice</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="width: auto">
            <th>NR</th>
            <td>2.6</td>
            <td>Can Improve</td>
            <td>5.0</td>
            <td>Excellent</td>
            <td>4.5</td>
            <td>Regressed</td>
          </tr>
          <!-- </tr> -->
        </ng-container>
    
      </table>
```

**N.B:** `attemptCounts(n)` is simply a function that returns an array of n elements. for example `attemptCounts(3)` will return `[0,1,2]`

I am willing to change the structure of my data.activities if it is going to make the table easier to generate. So please if anyone has a solution that works with a different data model, please do share.

the values "Getting Better", "Excellent" are entered by the instructor from a form field. So they could be constants or not. Or even just empty strings. That will work as well.

Can someone please help me dynamically generate this table? I have been struggling with this for days now, and I seem not able to find a solution that works for me.

SO, Please help a friend in distress.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment, but I do not think Material-table will help me achieve this specific architecture. I have looked into it, but I feel like this table is way to specific for mat-table to work in this instance. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @robert, my 'Colors' looks like this `this.colors = {Control: '#bfbfbf', 'AFCS': '#bfbfbf', ...}`. Subject array is just a result of grouping the activities array by `subject` where the key is the subject and the value is an array. I hope I answered your question. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I am willing to change the structure of my `data.activities` if it is going to make the table easier to generate. So please if anyone has a solution that works with a different data model, please do share. Thanks

Comment: @robert, As I explained, attemptCounts() is a function that simply returns an array of integer. So for example `attemptCounts(3)` will return `[0,1,2]`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, Thanks for your reply. the `data` object has a field called activities, and I would like to match certain fields to the `activities` list when I do the `ng-for-loop`. So those two pieces of data are different, but have some shared fields that I would like to match. Thanks again guys. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @robert, Yes the values "Getting Better", "Excellent" are entered by the instructor from a form field. So it could be a constants or not. Or even just empty strings. That will work as well. Thanks

Comment: Please update the question with your answers. So we can cleanup this Q/A section.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, You could do something like this `this.groupedActivities = customGroupByFunction(this.activities, 'activity')`;

Comment: @AllJs https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u6o5gu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html take this stacblitz and fork it first, then add your all code in this stackblitz and then share your updated code link of stackblitz here. It would be more helpful to understand it

Comment: Here is the stackblitz @robert https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xkatki?file=src/app/app.component.ts. I also updated the question with a link to stackblitz. Thanks

Comment: @AllJs here is demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v43h98?file=src%2Fapp%2Fget-length.pipe.ts check it out.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, thanks for your answer it seems to work. I have a new issue now. I am trying to use a dropdown to refresh the data on the table. Checkout this Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-to-update-table?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Thanks.

Comment: @AllJs here is your updated code https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-to-update-table-cjrrsy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts check it out.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, Thanks for your answer. I checked it out, but the issue is that it keeps adding columns every time the dropdown changes value, instead of simply redrawing the table with the new data. I was stuck at the same point too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233739/discussion-between-alljs-and-gaurangdhorda).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to make it work without changing the data structure.

First some Interfaces:

```
interface Activity {
  id: number;
  activity: string;
  subject: string;
  icon: string;
}

interface Attempt {
  grade: number;
  note: string;
}

interface ActivityAttemp {
  activityName: string;
  attempts: Attempt[];
}

interface ActivitiesBySubject {
  subject: string;
  activities: ActivityAttemp[];
}
```

Calculate Attempts count from `data.activities`:

```
attemptCounts: number[] = [];

const count =
  ((Object.values(this.data.activities)[0] as string[]).length - 1) / 2;
for (let i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
  this.attemptCounts.push(i);
}
```

Before giving data to Angular to render it some pre-processing:

```
this.subjects.forEach((subject: string) => {
  this.activitiesBySubject.push({
    subject,
    activities: this.activities
      .filter((act: Activity) => act.subject === subject)
      .map((act: Activity) => {
        return {
          activityName: act.activity,
          attempts: this.getAttemptsForActivity(act.activity)
        };
      })
  });
});
```

The idea is to have all needed data in one place this way HTML template becomes much simpler:

```
<div style="overflow: auto">
  <table>
    <caption>Session Summary</caption>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 40%"></th>
      <th style="width: auto"></th>
      <th style="width: auto" colspan="2" *ngFor="let attempt of attemptCounts">Attempt {{attempt}}</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th style="width: 40%">Subject Grouping</th>
      <th style="width: auto">Activity</th>

      <ng-container *ngFor="let attemptLabel of attemptCounts">
        <th style="width: auto">Grade</th>
        <th style="width: auto">Note</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>


    <ng-container *ngFor="let actsBySubj of activitiesBySubject">

      <tr>
        <td [attr.rowspan]="actsBySubj.activities.length + 1">
          {{ actsBySubj.subject }}
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr *ngFor="let activity of actsBySubj.activities">
        <td>
          {{ activity.activityName }}
        </td>

        <ng-container *ngFor="let attempt of activity.attempts">

          <td>
            {{attempt.grade}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{attempt.note}}
          </td>

        </ng-container>

      </tr>

    </ng-container>

  </table>
</div>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gezpws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Thanks @GaurangDhorda for initial Stackblitz.

**UPDATE**

To work with dropdown the processing has to be moved to a separate method:

```
  private calcTableData() {
    // reset
    this.attemptCounts = [];
    this.activitiesBySubject = [];

    // find exercise from "selectedExerciseId"
    const selectedExercise = this.data.find(
      (x: any) => x.id === this.selectedExerciseId
    );

    if (!selectedExercise) {
      return; // unable to find exercise
    }

    // calc attempt count eg.: 1, 2, 3
    for (let i = 1; i <= selectedExercise.attemptCount; ++i) {
      this.attemptCounts.push(i);
    }

    this.subjects.forEach((subject: string) => {
      this.activitiesBySubject.push({
        subject,
        activities: this.activities
          .filter((act: Activity) => act.subject === subject)
          .map((act: Activity) => {
            return {
              activityName: act.activity,
              attempts: this.getAttemptsForActivity(
                selectedExercise,
                act.activity
              )
            };
          })
      });
    });

    console.log(this.activitiesBySubject);
  }
```

This method uses a member variable `selectedExerciseId` to get the selected item. Also the color palette is moved to:

```
  colors: { [key: string]: string } = {
    Control: '#bfbfbf',
    AFCS: '#fac090',
    'Situational Awareness': '#c4bd97',
    'Leadership / Teamwork': '#d99694',
    Communication: '#c3d69b',
    'PB. Solving / Decision Making': '#b3a2c7'
  };
```

Event handler `onChange` and life cycle hook `ngOnit` just calls `calcTableData`:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.calcTableData();
  }

  onChange(e: Event) {
    this.calcTableData();
  }
```

Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-to-update-table-mk5gpb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hey @Robert Thanks for your answer. It works as expected. I really appreciate your help on this. My last would be this: How could I apply the color palette I previously created to each subject matter, using the `setColorPalette()` function. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you. Here is what I did to apply the colors scheme to each subject

 `<td [attr.rowspan]="actsBySubj.activities.length + 1" [style.background]="colors[actsBySubj.subject]">
          {{ actsBySubj.subject }}
        </td>`. All I added was the `[style.background]="colors[actsBySubj.subject]"`

Comment: Hey @Robert, please the question. I updated the question with a new issue. Dropdown to update the table. Here is the stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rnkym4?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Thanks

Comment: @AllJs link is broken

Comment: here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/dropdown-to-update-table?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Oh, if you can change your data structure please do.

```js
export interface Attempt {
  grade: number;
  note: string;
}

export interface Activity {
  name: string;
  attempts: Attempt[];
}

// in use
let activities: Activity[] = [
  {
    name: 'Power',
    attempts: [
      { grade: 3.5, note: 'Could do better' },
      { grade: 4.5, note: 'Better' },
      { grade: 5, note: 'Passed' },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: '',
    // etc…
  }
]
```

The problem of grouping rows still exists but a structure like this is going to be far easier to manage.